# Notice при if когда проверяю массив

Tags: php

Заношу в массив такие данные

```
$this->chests[$player->getName()] = new ChestMenu(
  $this, $player, $array, "particles", "§bВыберите режим"
);
```

Проверяю

```
if (!is_object($this->chests[$player->getName()])) return;
```

Вылазит Notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: Matrix51 in /root/server/bridge/plugins/TheBridgeAPI/src/truexackep/API.php on line 148

Спасибо

Comment: Значит в массиве `$this->chests` нет элемента с индексом `Matrix51`. Делайте `var_dump` и смотрите что у Вас переменных

Comment: я и хочу сделать проверку есть он или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте вот такую проверку еще:

```
isset($this->chests[$player->getName()])
```

Comment: isset не работает на объекти...

Comment: а в моем случае это объект ChestMenu

Comment: вам необходимо проверить есть ли ключик такой в массиве, а уже потом проверять объект ли там или что-то еще.

Comment: `$this->chests` у Вас массив, проверяйте через `isset`